# Get values from multiple div with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some jquery question :
I generate with php loop a list of div.
I would like when I click on 1 div, print alert with the value of the div.

First my html (result of php loop) code :

```
<div id="unlink_1" class="unlink_table" value="1" />
<img src="images/picto-table-unlink.png" />
</div>

<div id="unlink_2" class="unlink_table" value="2" />
<img src="images/picto-table-unlink.png" />
</div>

<div id="unlink_3" class="unlink_table" value="3" />
<img src="images/picto-table-unlink.png" />
</div>
```

My jquery code :

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
    var test = $(".unlink_table").val();
    alert(test);
});
```

For that moment it doesn't work (alert empty)

Thank you !

Comment: use `$(this).html();`

Comment: does value attribute for div works?

Comment: Try with `$(".unlink_table").text();`

Comment: in layman's language..jQuery doesn't know that for `$(".unlink_table").val();`  which `unlink_X` `div`s value needs to be picked...so you need `this` to point it out! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : Inside click event you have to use `$(this)` to refer to clicked element. You were calling `$(".unlink_table").val();` which will try to call `val()` for all element with `class="unlink_table"`. Also `.val()` will not work for `div`, you have to use `.attr('value')`.

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
    var test = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(test);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ybg7p1q/1/)**

Comment: div has no `val();` should use `html();` instead.

Comment: Thats ok now. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: +1 One of the few people who actually read the question before answering.

Answer (score 1):

To select the element on which you currently clicked, you should use `$(this)` function in your event handler.

No `value` attribute is available for `div` tag. use `data` attributes instead.

HTML:

```
<div id="unlink_3" class="unlink_table" data-value="3" />
    <img src="images/picto-table-unlink.png" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
    var test = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(test);
});
```

---

**OR** you can ad a hidden input in each div.

HTML:

```
<div id="unlink_3" class="unlink_table" />
    <input type="hidden" value=3" />
    <img src="images/picto-table-unlink.png" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
    var test = $(this).find('input').val();
    alert(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no value attribute for div

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
    //var test = $(this).html();
    //or
    var test= $(this).attr("value");

    alert(test);
});
```

Comment: You can use `attr('value')` as `value` is defined in html for `div`

Answer (score 0):

try with `$(this).attr()` you have added attribute `value` to div so get with `attr()` and `$(this)` refer to current div

```
$(".unlink_table").click(function(){
   var val = $(this).attr('value');
   alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No value method available for block element (DIVS) use HTML

```
 $(".unlink_table").click(function(e){
    var abc= $(this).html();
    alert(abc);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use somethig like this.

```
$('.unlink_table').on('click',function(){ 
var test = $(this).html();
alert(test);
});
```

this is very helpful when your using ajax calls because it keep DOM alive.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
$("div[id^='unlink_']").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(".unlink_table").click(function(){
         var test = $(".unlink_table").attr('value');
         alert(test);
      });
```

Hope the above code will work for you. As DIV does not have the "VALUE" attribute in it you can't print it using val() method. I would like to request you to use data-val instead of value and use the following code :

```
        $(".unlink_table").click(function(){
         var test = $(".unlink_table").data('val');
         alert(test);
      });
```